# Set the height and width of EditField on BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-editfield

I want to set the height and width of an `EditField` in my BlackBerry app.

Comment: how can i get more responses???

Comment: This question has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338671/blackberry-custom-size-editfield

Answer (score 8):

You need to override the field's layout method to set the size for you:

```
protected void layout(int width, int height)
{
    super.layout(customWidth, customHeight);
    setExtent(customWidth, customHeight);
}
```

where `customWidth` and `customHeight` have been set by you elsewhere.

- `super.layout(customWidth, customHeight)` lays the field out to use your special width & height.
- `setExtent(customWidth, customHeight)` sets the size of the field on the screen.

---

You can do this when you declare your EditField using code similar to the below code:

```
final int customWidth = Display.getWidth();
final int customHeight = 30;

Field myEditField = new EditField()
{
    protected void layout(int width, int height)
    {
        super.layout(customWidth, customHeight);
        setExtent(customWidth, customHeight);
    }

};
```

Comment: Instead of:
Field myEditField = new EditField()

Should be:
EditField myEditField = new EditField()

Comment: @Sarang That depends on what you want to do, remember that `EditField` is a subclass of `Field`.

Answer (score 3):

You can also pace the edit field inside a horizontalFieldmanager and override the sublayout method to set the height and width of horizontalfieldmanager for setting the height & width of editfield

Comment: overriding `sublayout()` sort of defeats the purpose of using a `HorizontalFieldManager` (versus just extending `Manager`).  I've also seen lots of strange problems when people did this.  In general, if people really want fine layout control, they should either decide that it's the Manager's job, and subclass `Manager`, or decide that it's an inherent property of the child `Field`, and do what Richard's answer suggests.

Answer (score 1):

- Note 1 : You can't set the width and height for `editField`
- Note 2 : You use just the `sublayout`  method  in manager
- Note 3 : If you add the `editField`  to the screen it will fill all the available width from the beginning to the end of screen

You can use this idea by putting some fields in the left side and putting your `editField` in the last.

Or, you can use the below code.

You will set the width and height of both the manager and  the edit field and try to put them on the screen:

```
HorizontalFieldManager containerManager = new HorizontalFieldManager() {
    public int getPreferredHeight() {
        return super.getPreferredHeight();
    }

    public int getPreferredWidth() {
        return super.getPreferredWidth();
    } 

    protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
        setExtent(getPreferredWidth(), getPreferredHeight());
        super.sublayout(getPreferredWidth(), getPreferredHeight());
    }
};


EditField editField = new EditField(Field.FIELD_VCENTER) {
    public int getPreferredHeight() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.getPreferredHeight();
    }

    public int getPreferredWidth() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.getPreferredWidth();
    } 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to modify the height of an EditField is by fiddling with the padding around the borders like this:

```
EditField emailField = new EditField("", "optional initial text");

XYEdges xyEdge = new XYEdges(2, 2, 2, 2);
XYEdges xyEdgeColors = new XYEdges(0x00dddddd, 0x00dddddd, 0x00dddddd, 0x00dddddd);
Border aBorder = BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(xyEdge, xyEdgeColors, Border.STYLE_SOLID);

emailField.setBorder(aBorder);
emailField.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 10);
```