# ButtonField doesn't appear in HorizontalFieldManager

Tags: button, blackberry, horizontalfieldmanager

I have added a buttonField into a HorizontalFieldManager in Blackberry app. I added it after adding an EditField. Yet the buttonField doesnt appear.
Below is my code

```
HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontlFieldManager(); 
    BasicEditField edit = new BasicEditField("Label", "UP");
    ButtonField button = new ButtonField("Search");
    hfm.add(edit);
    hfm.add(button);
    add(hfm);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer won't solve your problem, but it is important to note that **your code is absolutely fine**, and there's nothing wrong with it.

`HorizontalFieldManager` class is full of bugs introduced in OS 5.0 and as for today (latest version are 7.x) RIM has shown no intention whatsoever of fixing it.

As a sample, [here's a bug issue](https://www.blackberry.com/jira/browse/JAVAAPI-1366) in BB Developer Issue Tracker and still unresolved. I've had to deal with hfm in my latest project and also faced issues I had to workaround by creating my own manager, in a similar way as [Shashank's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12439551/813951) shows. You can find more examples on creating a custom manager in SO. Also [here](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800505/800508/How_To_-_Create_a_custom_layout_manager_for_a_screen.html?nodeid=800263&vernum=0) are covered the basics.

This is currently the only solution, since RIM is transitioning to BB 10 (C++), and they are dumping the Java API, so don't expect them to fix it anytime soon. Even if they were, it won't be fixed but on the latest OS version, which is useless since BB devices are rarely upgraded.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set editfield width & button width

```
protected void layout(int width,int height)
{
super.layout(Display.getWidth() * 3 /4  , getpreferedHeight());
super.setExtent(Display.getWidth() * 3/4    , getpreferedHeight());
}
```

For button use

```
protected void layout(int width,int height)
{
super.layout(Display.getWidth() /4  , getpreferedHeight());
super.setExtent(Display.getWidth() /4   , getpreferedHeight());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [Shashank was basically on the right track](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12439551/119114), but for a more complete example of how to change the `ButtonField` width, I would [recommend looking at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8167656/119114).

Answer (score -1):

take VerticalFieldManager insted of HorizantalFieldManager

Comment: I want to add the buttonfield next to the editfield, not below it

Comment: ONCE TRY THIS.....limit the charecters upto some extent like EditField editField = new EditField("","",10,EditField.EDITABLE);